# Correct Apple Watch icon sizes and resolution?

Tags: xcode, icons, app-store, resolution, apple-watch

The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/IconandImageSizes.html) are a little confusing, but what I can tell from Xcode warnings, the correct Apple Watch icon sizes are the following:

1. 24pt = 48x48px
2. 27.5pt = 55x55px
3. 29pt@2x = 58x58px
4. 29pt@3x = 87x87px
5. 40pt@2x = 80x80px
6. 44pt = 88x88px
7. 86pt = 172x172px
8. 98pt = 196x196px

I have a large 1024px version of my icon and want to generate the above sizes, but what is the dpi to use (Pixelmator defaults to 72dpi which seems to be optimized for web only). Is it ok to do it this way?

[image]

Comment: I've just done it the way you are contemplating with no warnings. App submitted but too early to tell if all's well.

Comment: @TruMan1 Any updates? I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: I used Sketch's default export settings and everything went through. I believe it is 72dpi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually work with 72dpi to submit app icons. It won't make any warning. You don't need Pixelmator. You can use Preview to do that and even change the dpi (Tools ==> Adjust Size... and change the dpi to whatever you like).

The sizes are correct, however it is better to remove alpha channels.